# Expected 2-3 arguments , but got 1 (ionic ) typescript

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

```
registerStudent(id,cName)
{
  return this.http.put("http://localhost:3000/api/registerOnlyThisStudent/"+id+"/"+cName).subscribe((res) =>{console.log(res.json());
 });
}

markRegistered(id)
{
  return this.http.put("http://localhost:3000/api/markRegistered/"+id).subscribe((res) =>{console.log(res.json());
 });
 }

  unRegister(sName ,cName )
   {
    return this.http.put("http://localhost:3000/api/UnRegister/"+sName+"/"+cName).subscribe((res) =>{console.log(res.json());
   });
     }
```

[This is the error ,the code works perfectly fine in the browser but when I try to run the command ionic cordova run android , the compiler gives this error. please help me solve this issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyqed.png)

Comment: Please dont post error messages as images. Copy paste the text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It errors because the [method signature for put](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http/#put) is:

```
put(url, body, headers)
```

It still technically works because the library happens to gracefully handle the `undefined` values you are implicitly passing.

You can resolve this using empty objects if you don't want to send data or headers:

```
put(url, {}, {})
```